# Kartik GridView Pjax error in dropdown filter column

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, pjax

I'm using **Kartik GridView** for showing the data. In the column Status's, I've set **FILTER_SELECT2**.

This is the view of my gridview.

[image]

When I select a status from the filter dropdown, the table will refresh but it didn't show data base on **selected status** (Nothing change).

**This is the code from my index.php**

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\grid\GridView;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\modules\vatout\models\VatoutStatus;
use app\modules\vatout\assets\Asset;

Asset::register($this);
?>
<div class="vatout-faktur-out-index">
<?php Pjax::begin() ?>

<?=
GridView::widget([
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'pjax' => true,
    'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn',
        ],
            [
            'attribute' => 'invoice',
            'value' => function($data) {
                return $data->invoice;
                ;
            },
            'hAlign' => 'center',
            'width' => '175px',
        ],
            [
            'attribute' => 'date',
            'value' => function($data) {
                return $data->date;
            },
            'hAlign' => 'center',
            'width' => '110px',
        ],
            [
            'attribute' => 'prod_code',
            'value' => function($data) {
                return $data->prod_code;
            },
            'hAlign' => 'center',
            'width' => '185px',
        ],
            ['class' => 'kartik\grid\FormulaColumn',
            'attribute' => 'amount',
            'format' => ['currency'],
            'value' => function($data) {
                return $data->amount;
            },
            'mergeHeader' => true,
            'hAlign' => 'center',
            'width' => '160px',
        ],
            [
            'attribute' => 'comp_name',
            'value' => function($data) {
                return $data->comp_name;
            },
            'hAlign' => 'center',
            'width' => '320px',
        ],
            [
            'attribute' => 'scan_date',
            'value' => function($data) {
                return $data->scan_date;
            },
            'mergeHeader' => true,
            'hAlign' => 'center',
            'width' => '80px',
        ],
            [
            'attribute' => 'is_exported',
            'width' => '80px',
            'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
                return $model->isExported->name;
            },
            'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
            'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(VatoutStatus::find()->orderBy('id')->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
            'filterWidgetOptions' => [
                'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
            ],
            'filterInputOptions' => ['placeholder' => 'Any Status']
        ],
    ],
    'toolbar' => [
    ],
    'panel' => [
        'type' => GridView::TYPE_SUCCESS,
        'before' => '<p><button type="button" onclick="getRows()" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></i> DOWNLOAD CSV</button></p>', //IMPORTANT
    ],
    'persistResize' => false,
    'toggleDataOptions' => ['minCount' => 10]
]);
?>
<?php Pjax::end() ?>
```

**This is the view of VatoutStatus Table**

[image]

**This is the code of my searchModel:**

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = VatoutStatus::find();

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'disposal_id' => $this->disposal_id,
        'user_id' => $this->user_id,
        'parent_id' => $this->parent_id,
        'date' => $this->date,
        'amount' => $this->amount,
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'is_exported' => $this->is_exported,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'comp_name', $this->comp_name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'updated_by', $this->updated_by])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'created_by', $this->created_by]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

I've set the `'pjax' => true,` as the docs said.

**And I got this error from my browser inspect element:**
[image]

Why I got this error? some issue in SO and another articles said that because time out. But I don't know how to increase the `pjax` time limit.

#### Why does my PJAX got error? and How to solve it?

---

#### Solved

```
public function actionIndexSparepart() {
    $userId = Yii::$app->user->id;
    $searchModel = new VatoutFakturOutSearch();
    $dataProvider = new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => VatoutFakturOut::find()->
                where(['user_id' => $userId, 'vatout_type' => 1]),
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 100,
        ]
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove pjax

```
<?php // Pjax::begin() ?>
...
.
.
.
<?php //Pjax::end() ?>
```

and change action action

```
public function actionindex....(){
    $searchModel = new vatoutfakturoutSearch();
        $searchModel->user_id = $user_id;
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        return $this->render('userindex', [
                    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);

}
```

Comment: I've try your suggestions, and they didn't solve my issue yet. I've many questions, first from where `buy_search` come, and then I don't know exactly where I should put the code from your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: I've tried, but it's give me the same error. Is it possible the issue because the container id?

Comment: Tomorrow(15/7/2017) at 3.30 GMT. have telegram?please message me @amirajloo.I can answer from 13 pm.

Comment: Ok, I've added and sent you a message through telegram :)